# How to shift parent <div> diagonally in AngularJS custom directive

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

The following code sample works correctly: the colors of the dynamically generated `ellipse` elements iterate through the colors in an array.

As a variation, I'm trying to dynamically update the `style` property of the parent `div` element in a custom directive so that the `div` elements are essentially shifted downward and to the right by setting 'position' to `absolute` and also the **left** and **top** properties as a multiple of the **id** value of the corresponding `div` element.

Since the value of **id** is accessible in **compile**, it seems like a convenient location to update the parent **div**, but **tElem is undefined here**:

How do I access the parent element to update its style-related properties?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom SVG Directive in AngularJS</title>

  <style>
    div { width:80px; height: 40px; }
  </style>

  <script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.js">
  </script>

  <script>
   var app = angular.module("app", []);

   app.directive('div', function() {
       var colors = ["red", "green", "orange", "blue", "#fcc"];
       var color  = colors[0];
       var shape  = '<ellipse cx=40 cy=40 rx=30 ry=15 fill="'+color+'">';
       var mydir  = {};
       mydir.restrict = 'E'; 
       mydir.template = '<svg>'+shape+'</svg>';

       mydir.compile = function(tElem, tAttrs){
                         var id = tAttrs['id'];
                         color = colors[id % colors.length];
                         var shape = 
                           '<ellipse cx=40 cy=40 rx=30 ry=15 fill="'+color+'">';
                         mydir.template = '<svg>'+shape+'</svg>';


                       //==============================================
                       // set a 'position:absolute;' property for <div>
                       // and also shift the <div> element diagonally: 
                       // var left = id*80, top = id*40;
                       // tElem.style.left = left+"px";
                       // tElem.style.top  = top+"px";
                       // tElem.style.position = "absolute";
                       //==============================================
       };

       return mydir;
   })

   app.controller("MyController", function() {});
  </script>
 </head>

 <body ng-controller="MyController as mc" >
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
  <div id="5"></div>
  <div id="6"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current way you are doing is correct but when you want to change the `style` of element you need to use actual DOM of that elemenet by doing `tElem[0]` which will have DOM of that `div` element.

**Code**

```
tElem[0].style.left = left+"px";
tElem[0].style.top  = top+"px";
tElem[0].style.position = "absolute";
```

[**Using Style Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1EWvB7iy3iOuueknCH2p?p=preview)

### Better way

Better should all the css property to `.css` method of jQLite, which would accept all the properties in json format with their values.

**Code**

```
tElem.css({
  'left': left + "px",
  top: top  + "px",
  position: 'absolute'
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1iCoNx4m0nD2u3DMQmoR?p=preview)